# Delphi Change Hex Address on file

Tags: delphi

I wanna over delphi change hex adress 15 character,

[image]

I follow like this a way but I didnt get success,

```
BlockRead(F,arrChar,1);                  //read all to the buf
CloseFile(F);                            //close file
IMEI:=Form1.Edit1.Text;                  //get the number
Form1.Memo1.Lines.Add('new IMEI is'+IMEI);    //output 

for i:=524288 to 524288+15 do               /
  arrChar[i]:=IMEI[i-524287];
```

Answer (score 2):

Do this with a file stream.

```
var
  Stream: TFileStream;
....
Stream := TFileStream.Create(FileName, fmOpenWrite);
try
  Stream.Position := $080000;
  Stream.WriteBuffer(IMEI, SizeOf(IMEI));
finally
  Stream.Free;
end;
```

I'm assuming that IMEI is an fixed length array of bytes of length 15 but your code attempts to write 16 bytes so it would appear that you are suffering from a degree of confusion.

In your code, your variable IMEI is a string. Which is not an array of bytes. Please don't make that classic mistake of regarding a string as an array of bytes.

You might declare an IMEI type like this:

```
type
  TIMEI = array [0..14] of Byte;
```

Then you might write a function to populate such a variable from text:

```
function TextToIMEI(const Text: string): TIMEI;
var
  ResultIndex, TextIndex: Integer;
  C: Char;
begin
  if Length(Text) <> Length(Result) then
    raise SomeExceptionClass.Create(...);

  TextIndex := low(Text);
  for ResultIndex := low(Result) to high(Result) do 
  begin
    C := Result[TextIndex];
    if (C < '0') or (C > '9') then
      raise SomeExceptionClass.Create(...);
    Result[ResultIndex] := ord(C);
    inc(TextIndex);
  end;
end;
```

You might then combine this code with that above:

```
procedure WriteIMEItoFile(const FileName: string; FileOffset: Int64; const IMEI: TIMEI);
var
  Stream: TFileStream;
begin
  Stream := TFileStream.Create(FileName, fmOpenWrite);
  try
    Stream.Position := FileOffset;
    Stream.WriteBuffer(IMEI, SizeOf(IMEI));
  finally
    Stream.Free;
  end;
end;
```

Call it like this:

```
WriteIMEItoFile(FileName, $080000, TextToIMEI(Form1.Edit1.Text));
```

Although it looks a bit odd that you are explicitly using the `Form1` global variable. If that code executes in a method of `TForm1` then you should use the implicit `Self` variable.